# How to add a header file to the c project?

Tags: c, header-files

Am using a Dev c++ compiler, to compile a c code. (I am a beginner)
When I compile, it says 'some' header files are missing.
How can i include those header files in my system, so as to be utilized by the program??

Thanks

Comment: It depends on which functions or symbols you are using in your program ,accordingly you have to include those files in the starting of the program

Comment: I have included those header files. But compiler cant find those header files in the system.

Comment: Do you have the header files in the same folder as the program you are compiling in? *assuming you are writing your own header files

Comment: Also which api you are using ..either `win32` or `posix`..It depends on that

Comment: Kiith: The folder contains only the c program. Sorry I dont know from where, the compiler find the header files and I like to know. ( I think it is accessing some header files from MinGW gcc compiler).

Comment: Omkant: Sorry how can i know, which API am using?

Comment: What are the header files you are tying to use?

Comment: Actually its sys/ipc.h and sys/sem.h

Comment: Would it be safe to assume you are programming on Windows?

Answer (score 1):

A header such as `<sys/sem.h>` which is used for the function `semget()` among other things, is not generally available in Windows. It's a POSIX header, and Windows does not implement the POSIX standard out of the box.

You should maybe look at the Win32 API instead, for instance a function like `CreateSemaphore()`.

Comment: So its impossible to use POSIX header in the Windows? Not possible to make it possible?. Just asking

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to use the Linux API on Windows. Here is what is going on: Every operating system has its own set of libraries for programmers to use to make programs on that platform. In this instance, you are attempting to use Linux libraries on Windows. Windows doesn't have a code location called sys/ipc or sys/sem.

Furthermore, since you said you are a beginner, try finding another tutorial. sys/ipc.h and sys/sem.h are not for beginners, are are libraries typically used for communication between processes. These concepts are way beyond you right now haha :P

Here is a better place to start: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c-tutorial.html

Comment: Ya sure.. I check the link. Btw, not possible use linux API on Windows? Is there any way I can include those header files in the windows, like copying the whole 'include' folder from the linux to the windows?

Comment: Not unless there was some kind of like... project to do so. I am not really sure why someone would want to use Linux libraries for Windows anyway. If you are really keen on using Linux code, just program on Linux haha.

Comment: You can take the code from Linux and put it on Windows, but you will just have the exact same problem you are having right now. Those libraries also use other Linux-specific code.

Comment: I really suggest you use that link, or find some other beginner tutorial. I mean, you really aren't ready yet to be playing around with inter process communication and synchronization stuff. If you insist on it though, you can download VMware player, and install Linux on it. You will need to learn how to use GCC though, unless you can find some other kind of ide lol.

Comment: I too feel its funny but sorry again: I dont want to use Linux and I want to use semget() function to be executed in the Windows. So am in the dead end? or solutions I think are follows: 1. have a kinda header file which converts semget() to createsemaphore() kinda functions. or 2. Copy the actual header files from Linux and have it  on Windows. If I do so, what kinda problems I face? Or am I missing some basics like API or OS?

Comment: You can't bring over Linux header files and put it on Windows and have it work. You would have to figure out how Windows supports inter process communication and semaphores. The reason you can't just bring over the Linux code is because Linux is its own OS and each library is going to depend on some other one. You would have to bring over the entirety of Linux code, build it, and run it in the same "space" as Windows which is impossible.